# How to pass or get the value from Map (random generator) to PebbleStringBody in Gatling with Scala

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling, pebble

How to pass or get the value from Map (random generator) to **PebbleStringBody** in Gatling with Scala

```
  val names = Iterator.continually {
    Map("name" -> s"PerfTest ${Random.alphanumeric.take(10).mkString}")
  }

.feed(names)
    .exec(http("PerfTest")
      .post("/PerfTest/bulk")
      .body(PebbleStringBody(
       """| [
          |  {% set Iteratecount = 2 %}
          | {% for t in range(1,Iteratecount) %}
          |    {
          |   "name": "{{name}}",    //cannot get the value from feeder :Map or from Json path 
          |   "TestID": "9888988FRFRFDD887887ESES",
          |   "typeId": "9888988FRFRFDD887887ESES",
          |   "statusId": "9888988FRFRFDD887887ESES",
          |   "excludedFromAutoHyperlinking": true
          |    }
          |  {% if loop.last %}
          |  {% else %},{% endif %}
          |  {% endfor %}
          |  ]""".stripMargin)).asJson
      .check(status.is(200))
    )
```

also could not pass the value from jsonPath to pebbleString body

`.check(jsonPath("$.result.name").saveAs("name")`

Please help with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your sample (against `google.com`) with TRACE logging enabled, using Gatling 3.8.4 and it works perfectly fine:

```scala
class PebbleSimulation extends Simulation {

  val names = Iterator.continually {
    Map("name" -> s"PerfTest ${Random.alphanumeric.take(10).mkString}")
  }

  val httpProtocol =
    http.baseUrl("https://google.com")
      .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
      .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
      .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
      .userAgentHeader(
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0"
      )

  val users = scenario("Users")
    .feed(names)
    .exec(http("PerfTest")
      .post("/PerfTest/bulk")
      .body(PebbleStringBody(
        """| [
           |  {% set Iteratecount = 2 %}
           | {% for t in range(1,Iteratecount) %}
           |    {
           |   "name": "{{name}}",    //cannot get the value from feeder :Map or from Json path
           |   "TestID": "9888988FRFRFDD887887ESES",
           |   "typeId": "9888988FRFRFDD887887ESES",
           |   "statusId": "9888988FRFRFDD887887ESES",
           |   "excludedFromAutoHyperlinking": true
           |    }
           |  {% if loop.last %}
           |  {% else %},{% endif %}
           |  {% endfor %}
           |  ]""".stripMargin)).asJson
      .check(status.is(200))
    )

  setUp(
    users.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

```
HTTP request:
POST https://google.com/PerfTest/bulk
headers:
    content-type: application/json
    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
    accept: application/json
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
    host: google.com
    content-length: 564
body:StringRequestBody{charset=UTF-8, content= [
       {
   "name": "PerfTest mAQ6evSHPW",    //cannot get the value from feeder :Map or from Json path
   "TestID": "9888988FRFRFDD887887ESES",
   "typeId": "9888988FRFRFDD887887ESES",
   "statusId": "9888988FRFRFDD887887ESES",
   "excludedFromAutoHyperlinking": true
    }
  ,      {
   "name": "PerfTest mAQ6evSHPW",    //cannot get the value from feeder :Map or from Json path
   "TestID": "9888988FRFRFDD887887ESES",
   "typeId": "9888988FRFRFDD887887ESES",
   "statusId": "9888988FRFRFDD887887ESES",
   "excludedFromAutoHyperlinking": true
    }
        ]}
```

Either you're using an old buggy version of Gatling, or your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks you @Stéphane LANDELLE 

, I still see there is an issue here the **name** value should change at every iteration but i see its same. so its not dynamic when iteration is provided inside pebble string?
How can I handle the **for loop**?

Also can you provide an example with **session attributes (Json Path stored value)** passing to PebbleStringBody please. Will be a great help for me

Comment: "so its not dynamic when iteration is provided inside pebble string?" No, it's not. You just get new values every time the virtual user go through the `feed` action.

Comment: If you have another question, then validate this answer to this question, and create a new question.